# Tables in sqliteDatabase

Tags: android

I am in the process of creating a sqlitedatabase in android with three tables in it. The tables have nothing to do with the other table or doesn't need any information from the other table. What is the best way to design the tables. Do I have to set the foreign keys or I should skip that?
Newbie in sqlite development.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No relationships between the tables means no foreign keys.
Just set primary keys they are always usefull :)